# Making Nav menu item & caret both clickable (and on the same line)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been working on a solution with Twitter Bootstrap to make main navigation expand when you hover on a desktop, but the menu will expand when clicking the caret mobile (caret hidden on desktop). Additionally, I wanted the top level nav item to be clickable on mobile.

**What I have accomplished:**

- Sub menu expands on hover (desktop)
- Top level nav is clickable (desktop & mobile)
- Caret is hidden on desktop but shows up on mobile
- Clickable area for caret expands & collapses (mobile)

**What isn't working properly:**

- Top level nav item exapnds entire line (mobile)
- The expand/collapse area for the caret is on a second line (see black bar below "Services" in screenshot - mobile)

**What I would like to happen (see screenshot):**

- The clickable area to the right of the red line be for expand/collapse of menu (mobile)
- Clickable area left of red line be for visiting the "Services" top level nav page (mobile)

In short, desktop version is working exactly as I was hoping, but have outstanding issues with mobile version. Of course, the percentages don't have to match up perfectly with the red line, but I would essentially like two click events on the same line; one for visiting the Service page, and the other for expanding the Services sub menu.

Here is my current HTML setup for Twitter Bootstrap with the only custom CSS I have added as well as the screenshot of the current view on mobile. Bad color scheme chosen for clarity.

```
<ul id="menu-mainnav" class="nav"><li><a href="http://localhost">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
         <a href="http://localhost/services" data-hover="dropdown" data-target="#" class="dropdown-toggle pull-left js-activated disabled">Services</a>
         <a data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#"><b class="caret pull-right hidden-desktop"></b></a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <li><a href="http://localhost/services/service1">Service 2</a></li>
             <li><a href="http://localhost/services/service2">Service 1</a></li>
         </ul>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
@import url('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css');
@import url('bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css');
body {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
} 
.caret {border-top: 6px solid #fff; border-right: 6px solid transparent; border-left: 6px solid transparent;}
.dropdown .caret {margin-top: -20px;}
```

**Screenshot of current issue**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with it a little bit, here is my solution that worked for me.

```
<ul id="menu-mainnav" class="nav"><li><a href="http://localhost">Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="http://localhost/services" data-hover="dropdown" data-target="#" class="dropdown-toggle pull-left js-activated disabled testdd">Services</a>
                    <b data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" class="caret pull-right hidden-desktop rh-caret" style="width:6px; float:right;background-position:50% -133px; height:6px;"></b>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="http://localhost/services/service1">Service 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost/services/service2">Service 1</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
```